# iOS 6.0 orientation support, needs solution

Tags: objective-c, ios6, uiinterfaceorientation

I have 5 controllers in my Application and i am adding those controllers as 
[window addSubview:navController.view]; And array of 5 controllers given to navController which is UINavigationController.

Please help, on how to apply orientation support on those 5 view controllers?.
I have tried shouldAutoRotate to YES. But it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Change you code from:

```
[self.window addSubview:aController.view];
```

to

```
self.window.rootViewController = aController;
```

Also add the following methods for orientation support

shouldAutorotate -return YES

supportedInterfaceOrientations- return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft;